# Access file that is not publicly accessible to add to calendar

Tags: php, icalendar

I am trying to access an ics file that is kept away from public access, but allowing the logged in user to access the file, so they can add it to their calendar.

This is my code thus far:

```
    // Assign the location of the persons ics files to a variable to use later, then scan through all the files
    // and place them in an array.
    $personCalendars = '../folder01/calendars/person';
    $personFiles = scandir($personCalendars);

    // Find the ID of the person hat is logged in by looking through the session information.
    $personID = $_SESSION['person_ID'];

    // Get the url of the page that we are on and check the server name.
    function url(){
        return sprintf('%s//%s%s',
        isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https:' : 'http:',
            $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        );
    }

    // Find the ID of the person in the file array
    $getURL = preg_grep('/'.$personID.'/',$personFiles);

    // Set the pointer of the array to the first part of the url
    $filename = reset($getURL);

    // If there is an ics file for the person, grab the URL of the page and add on the filename 
    // eg: portal.company/index.php/calendar?99203.ics
    // If no file is found, say so.
    if ($filename){
        $fullURL =  url() . '?' . $filename;
        echo $fullURL;
    }else{
        echo 'File not found\n';
    }
```

This works great for getting a URL onto the page, however it does not create a valid link.

I have looked at [`fpassthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) but it it broke the page(using the example supplied in the manual).

Any suggestions on the best practice to link the URL to the file it should be linking to?

*Just FYI - I am new to PHP so I could be going about this all wrong.*

Comment: Requiring a login for an `.ics` file is super annoying, don't do it. Instead make a "secret" URL for the resource, in other words, something you couldn't guess or poke around randomly and find. An identifier that's 30+ random letters is generally a good place to start. Many calendar apps refuse to add `.ics` resources that require authentication, they just don't support it.

Comment: You'll also want to be sure that whatever URL scheme you choose doesn't change very often, if ever. Switching a calendar's URI source can be annoying, if not impossible, sometimes it's easier to recreate it as a new calendar, which ends up losing history.

Comment: The ics is being made as part of a student management system and being pushed to the a accompanying student portal displaying the students grades, reports, details etc so it does need to be via a login. It is being generated as JSON file and I am stripping out the information by student ID so the file URL will not change unless the server admin changes the name of the server.

Comment: What I mean is you disclose the secret URL via login only, but anyone with that URL can download the ICS data. This sort of "secret URL" approach to securing data works best over HTTPS where it can't be snooped.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. The ics file just has the students timetable, so no personal information so at this stage it is not a worry if another student gets another students timetable. Encryption and "secret url" is planned for future development. We are just wanting to know if people are wanting to use it for now.